# How to add flag for the LLVM IR instructions in Intrinsics.td file?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

How to add flag for the LLVM IR instruction in Intrinsics.td file? For example, I need to mark whether the instruction is unary op or binary op.

Thanks.

I can use TSFlags if in machine ir phase, but what about in LLVM IR phase?